# Efficient left_join and subsequent merge

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)

a<-data.frame("one"=c(1:10),
              "two"=c("","","","","a","a","a","a","a","a"), stringsAsFactors = F)

b<-data.frame("one"=c(4,2,6),
              "two"=c("C","D","A"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to `left_join` `b` onto `a`, such that `a$two` gets the value of `b$two` whenever `a$one == b$one`. This I do like this:

```
left_join(a, b, by="one")
```

In order to have the same structures as before, we can do the following

```
left_join(a, b, by="one") %>% 
  mutate(two=ifelse(is.na(two.y), two.x, two.y)) %>% 
  select(-c(two.x, two.y))
```

This gives me the desired output:

```
   one two
1    1    
2    2   D
3    3    
4    4   C
5    5   a
6    6   A
7    7   a
8    8   a
9    9   a
10  10   a
```

Is there a way to perform the `left_join` such that it isn't necessary to `mutate` and `select` to obtain the desired output? I.e., is there a more efficient way to get what I want? Right now it seems cumbersome to both `mutate` and `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are looking for a compact and efficient option, then this can be achieved with `data.table`.  After converting the 'a' to `data.table`, join `on` 'one' and assign (`:=`) the 'i.two' i.e. the column from 'b' to 'two' (from 'a')

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[b,two := i.two , on = .(one)]
a
#     one two
# 1:   1    
# 2:   2   D
# 3:   3    
# 4:   4   C
# 5:   5   a
# 6:   6   A
# 7:   7   a
# 8:   8   a
# 9:   9   a
#10:  10   a
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a common operation to perform on data, I'm surprised `dplyr` doesn't support a more compact and concise way to achieve this