# generic data frame update function with tidyverse dplyr like sql-update

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse, dplyr

I search for a generic data frame update function like the sql-update that updates values in the first data frame in case the keys match with the keys in the second data frame. Is there a more generic way as in my example, maybe also by considering the value names? Something like a generic dplyr::update(df1, df2, by = "key") function?

```
library(tidyverse)
# example data frame
df1 <- as_data_frame(list(key = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                          v1 = c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19),
                          v2 = c(21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29),
                          v3 = c(31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39),
                          v4 = c(41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49)))
df2 <- as_data_frame(list(key = c(3,5,9),
                          v2 = c(231,252,293),
                          v4 = c(424,455,496)))

# update df1 with values from df2 where key match
org_names <- df1 %>% names()
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "key") %>% 
  mutate(v2 = ifelse(is.na(v2.y), v2.x, v2.y),
         v4 = ifelse(is.na(v4.y), v4.x, v4.y)) %>% 
  select(org_names)

> df1
# A tibble: 9 x 5
key    v1    v2    v3    v4
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    11    21    31    41
2     2    12    22    32    42
3     3    13   231    33   424
4     4    14    24    34    44
5     5    15   252    35   455
6     6    16    26    36    46
7     7    17    27    37    47
8     8    18    28    38    48
9     9    19   293    39   496
>
```

Comment: I'm not aware of anything. However there is `dplyr::db_write_table` which has an argument to create a temporary table and `DBI::dbExecute` which you can use to execute an update using the newly created temporary table.

Comment: I also found a similar question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217477/efficient-left-join-and-subsequent-merge

with an answer to use data.table

Comment: Ah, I misread your question to be asking about making updates in an SQL database--you're just wanting to edit the local data frame object, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) %<>%** Magrittr has the compound assignment pipe:

```
library(magrittr)

df1 %>% 
    { keys <- intersect(.$key, df2$key)
    .[match(keys, .$key), names(df2)] %<>% { df2[match(keys, df2$key), ] }
    .
}
```

which, for the problem under consideration, simplifies to this because all keys in `df2` are in `df1`:

```
df1 %>% { .[match(df2$key, .$key), names(df2)]  %<>% { df2 }; . }
```

**2) <-** The basic R assignment operator could also be used in much the same way and, in fact, the code is shorter than (1):

```
df1 %>% 
    { keys <- intersect(.$key, df2$key)
    .[match(keys, .$key), names(df2)] <- df2[match(keys, df2$key), ]
    .
}
```

however, for the problem under consideration all keys in `df2` are in `df1` so it simplifies to:

```
df1 %>% { .[match(df2$key, .$key), names(df2)] <- df2; . }
```

**3) mutate_cond** Using `mutate_cond` defined in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096162/dplyr-mutate-replace-on-a-subset-of-rows) we can write the following.

```
df1 %>% mutate_cond(.$key %in% df2$key, v2 = df2$v2, v4 = df2$v4)
```

**Note:**  The first two approaches work if the keys in `df1` and `df2` are each unique. The third additionally requires the keys be in the same order and every key in df2 be in df1.  The problem in the question satisfies these.

**Update:** Have somewhat generalized the code in (1) and (2).